# Hash::check always return false

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on app in Laravel 5.5. I use Sentinel and I have problems when I check the login password:
`Hash::check()`
always returns false .

This is my code:

```
$email    = $request['email'];
$password = $request['password'];
$userId = User::where('email',$email)->first();
Hash::check($password, $userId->password);
```

It always returns false and I'm sure the password is correct.
Any help?

Comment: How are you generating the hash when you create the user row?

Comment: Are you sure you're not storing plain text password in the table?

Comment: Are you sure that you are generate password like this snd store it in DB?  
`Hash::make($request['password'])`

Comment: var_dump(Hash::make($password));
var_dump($userId->password);

check if the same

Comment: @Cezary Using `Hash::make` on the same password will most likely _not_ generate the same hash.

Comment: i use Hash::make for store the password

Comment: I think You've problem with `APP_KEY`, I mean in db You've password hashed by one APP_KEY, now You've different app key. Can You just generate password and keep it in db and check again?

Comment: @num8er hashing isn't encrypting

Comment: @lagbox wow! You've opened my eyes to true. Thanks Cap! Do You know what is salt in hashing technique? Also laravel does not use md5 for hashing, so app key can be used as iv_key in crypto lib that makes a hash.

Comment: @num8er  I know how the hashing works ... The APP_KEY has nothing to do with the hashing out of the box.

Comment: @lagbox darling, read this: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/283/generating-a-new-application-key

Comment: @num8er sorry you are incorrect ... that is untrue, you can change your app_key all you want and it wont effect the bcrypt hasher

Comment: @lagbox I've checked libs of laravel and I agree, You won. Let's meet I'll give You free beer (: